# FileReader.readAsDataUrl and m4a Files

Tags: javascript, html, file, filereader, qunit

I have a piece of JavaScript code that reads a m4a file as an ArrayBuffer and pulls out the metadata (title, artist etc.). I am trying to unit test it by using the data url of the file (a base64 string) to create a file blob which I can then parse. I have to do this in order to have the unit test run without any user interaction. I have done this successfully using mp3 files: I use the copy the output of FileReader.readAsDataUrl as a hard coded string in my test class and it works as expected. However when I try and do the same with a m4a file it does not work. Specifically the ArrayBuffer created from the data URL is not the same length as when the ArrayBuffer is created directly. Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Maybe the file was too big, try a very small file.

Comment: The mp3 that I did get to work is actually larger than the mp4 and it works (mp3 = ~6MB, m4a = ~2MB)